# Filtering a Django model on an AutoField

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model that looks like this -

```
class History(models.Model):
    testcaseidstring = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

I am storing String values in this field in the Database

When I make a query on this field like -

```
qs=qs.filter(testcaseidstring="tc123")
```

I get an error saying "**Field 'testcaseidstring' expected a number but got 'TC123'**"

How can I filter on this AutoField?

Is converting that field to a TextField the only way to go?

Any help would be highly appreciable

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#autofield),

> AutoField¶ 
> class AutoField(**options)¶ 
> An IntegerField that
> automatically increments according to available IDs. You usually won’t
> need to use this directly; a primary key field will automatically be
> added to your model if you don’t specify otherwise. See Automatic
> primary key fields

.

Using string for AutoField is a bad idea, if you look at the source code of AutoField class,

[https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/fields/init.py#L2516](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2516)

> ```
> class AutoField(AutoFieldMixin, IntegerField, metaclass=AutoFieldMeta):
>
>     def get_internal_type(self):
>         return 'AutoField'
>
>     def rel_db_type(self, connection):
>         return IntegerField().db_type(connection=connection)
> ```

AutoField is inherited from IntegerField. That is the reason you are getting,

> Field 'testcaseidstring' expected a number but got 'TC123'.

Answer (score 1):

From the Django documentation

> AutoField - class AutoField(**options)
>
> An **IntegerField** that automatically increments according to available
> IDs. You usually won’t need to use this directly; a primary key field
> will automatically be added to your model if you don’t specify
> otherwise. See Automatic primary key fields.

So a AutoField has to be an Integer. But you dont have to use a AutoField as the PrimaryKey. For example you can use a CharField as Primary.

```
testcaseidstring = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
```